# Send callback paramenter via Ajax jsonp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I've been looking for a good 3 hours and haven't found a way that works.
I'm super new to JQuery, Ajax, PHP.
All I'm looking for is how to set a callback parameter from an Ajax request using jsonp.
So basically im looking for this:
    `www.mysite.com/service.php?callback=value`
How can I change 'value' to whatever I want from an Ajax request...
Here's the last thing I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var output = $('#results');
$.ajax({
url: 'www.mysite.com/service.php',
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonp: 'callback',
jsonpCallback:'select',
timeout: 5000,
success: function(data,status){
    var result = data;
    output.append(result);
});
},
error: function(){
    output.text('Failed.');
}

});
});
```

My service.php is this

```
<?php
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
echo $callback;
?>
```

I'd expect to see a 'select' printed on my html.
And my html is just a basic html with a `<div id="results"></div>` in the body.

Thank you.

Comment: use data params of ajax function . visit below link.

http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2682

Comment: I tried this exact same tutorial but didn't work on my project. I copy/pasted the tutorial on a brand new html document and the php, and it worked. Guess there's something wrong with my project. Anyway, thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in service.php use `return $callback;`.

Next, create the select element inside the success function:

```
var select = document.createElement('select');
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.id = result;
option.value = result;
```

Comment: @JoséCisneros if this was worked please mark it as the correct answer :)